# Permission denied after document.open() in IE Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an error "Permission denied" when using the code follow

```
var data = "Hello, World! first";

document.open();
document.write(data);
document.close();
```

[image]

Note: It work fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.

Then, I change that to below:

```
window.document.open();
window.document.write(data);
window.document.close();
```

now it works fine, so could someone can explain for me why because I am new in Javascript.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this error?

Comment: More details on the workaround https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13171974/